# Python GUI - padding colour

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So i've created a frame here..

```
frame=Frame(master,  bg="grey")
frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, padx=15, expand=1)
self.canvas = Canvas(frame, height = 500, width = 7000, bg="white")
self.canvas.pack()
```

It has got some padding, however, i want the padding to have some color like blue. I don't know how to do that. I think the default is set to greyish-white.

Comment: Is this supposed to be in TkInter?

Answer (score 2):

The padding color is just the color of the container it is in. You can use another frame with whatever color that you want.

Your other option is to use the `highlightbackground` and `highlightthickness` options if you dont need them to serve their normal purpose (which is to show which widget has keyboard focus)